# .Net core API monitoring on linux machines

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, containers, newrelic

I am planning to deploy APIs created in .Net Core on linux. Currently we are using NewRelic .Net Agent for monitoring applications on windows servers.

I was not able to find a suitable solution for this combination.

Is there any other tool that I can use for monitoring .Net core APIs on linux boxes?

Can it be done using docker containers?

Comment: Ask NewRelic if they already have that in plan.

Comment: May Application Insights be an option?: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-asp-net-core/

Comment: @LexLi Newrelic dont have any solid plan to support .net core

Comment: @PeterBons I checked application insights but unfortunately cant use it on AWS.

Comment: People who have marked it as too broad at least please give me one solution and then mark it for close. If you dont have a solution, please stay away and let other people answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Dynatrace has introduced .NET Core Monitoring capabilities in September 2017 as a public beta: https://www.dynatrace.com/blog/announcing-immediate-support-for-net-core-for-linux/. It supports .NET Core 1.0, 1.1 and 2.0 on Windows and Linux. It also supports docker containers and can even inject agents without manual injection configuration.

Comment: Here is the always up-to-date set of supported .NET Core versions: https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/shortlink/supported-technologies#net-core

Answer (score 0):

As of late 2017, New Relic now supports instrumentation of .NET Core 2.0 applications running in Docker containers in Windows or Linux.

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/getting-started/compatibility-requirements-net-core-20-agent